# Is Asp.net Http Application Object suitable for Caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

i want to store user tokens which hold; expire time , last activity and user information (Username,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Type) , and i dont want to store this in db (im already storing in db but i want to access from **memory**) ,and this tokens are using from web,mobil and desktop applications.

And I dont want to use Session object , because i want to manage these tokens in singleton pattern.

is "Application" Object suitable for this ? or is there a limit of storing data in Application Object? Or what else we can do

Comment: why do you not use Cache?

Comment: Application doesn't make a lot of sense for this, because the values are never going to go away as long as the App Pool is alive.  A cache as @techspider suggested would be better, for this reason.

Comment: i usualy use cache (WebCache), but i had some issues with it (eg size problem,slower access and Thread issues )

Comment: You could take a look at [MemoryCache](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290935/Using-MemoryCache-in-Net-4-0) which allows singleton access to a cache object. Or you could research using Redis, especially if you're using Azure.

Comment: Whatever persistence model you end up using, **User token** must be **user** specific...

Comment: Im using these user tokens on realtime statistics